# rearranging a logarithmic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently working on a problem in which I have to equate two equations and rearrange to form another:

$$\alpha_1 + \beta_1\log⁡(w) + \gamma_1k = \alpha_2 + \beta_2\log⁡(w)$$

and obtain an equation for $\log(w)$ in terms of $k$ of the form $\log(w)=\pi_1 + \pi_2k$

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: thankyou, I will!

Comment: May be, define first $\log(w)=x$, rewrite the equation; solve it for $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the equation

$$\alpha_1+\beta_1\log(w)+\gamma_1k=\alpha_2+\beta_2\log(w)$$

Put terms with $\log(w)$ on a side and other constants on the other side and rearranging:

$$\beta_1 \log(w)-\beta_2\log(w)=\alpha_2-\alpha_1-\gamma_1k$$

$$(\beta_1 -\beta_2)\log(w)=\alpha_2-\alpha_1-\gamma_1k$$

Divide both sides by $\beta_1 -\beta_2$ :

$$\log(w)=\frac{\alpha_2-\alpha_1}{\beta_1 -\beta_2}-\frac{\gamma_1}{\beta_1 -\beta_2}k$$

Comment: thankyou thankyou thankyou!!!